# Use a stored procedure to get a list of nvarchar(20) values as a parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm developing a SQL Server 2012 stored procedure.

I need to return a list of nvarchar(20) values, and I don't know how can I do it. I have tried this:

1. Using a Table-Valued Parameters but it must be `READONLY`.
2. Doing a select to return that list. But stored procedures only
   returns `INT` values.

Any idea?

**UPDATE**:
This is what I have done:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAggregationChildren]
    @parentCode nvarchar(20),
    @codeLevel tinyint output,
    @returnValue int output
AS
    declare @childsLevelCount tinyint
          , @invalidChildCodesCount int;    

    set nocount on;
    -- ======== VALIDATION ==========
    if NULLIF(@parentCode, '') IS NULL
    begin
        set @returnValue = -19;
        return NULL; -- Parameter null or empty.
    end

    -- Check if parent exists in AGGREGATIONS table.
    if not exists (Select top 1 CODE from AGGREGATIONS where CODE = @parentCode)
    begin
        set @returnValue = -11;
        return NULL;
    end

    set @childsLevelCount = (select count(c.CODE_LEVEL) from CODES c where c.CODE in (Select CODE from AGGREGATION_CHILDS where PARENT_CODE = @parentCode) group by c.CODE_LEVEL);

    -- If this aggregation has children codes with different values, it is an error.
    if (@childsLevelCount > 1)
    begin
        set @returnValue = -201;
        return NULL;
    end

    -- =========== CODE =============
    set @returnValue = 0;

    set @codeLevel = (select c.CODE_LEVEL from CODES c where c.CODE in (Select CODE from AGGREGATION_CHILDS where PARENT_CODE = @parentCode) group by c.CODE_LEVEL);

    select CODE from AGGREGATION_CHILDS where PARENT_CODE = @parentCode;
```

But, I have no idea about how to return the result of this select:
`select CODE from AGGREGATION_CHILDS where PARENT_CODE = @parentCode;`

This stored procedure returns this on SQL Server Management Studio:
[image]

It is also returning a 0. I thought that the stored procedure is going to return the select result only.

I need the result in a parameter because I going to use in a `SQLCommand` like this one:

```
SqlParameter childsParam = new SqlParameter();
childsParam.ParameterName = "@childs";
childsParam.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured;
childsParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
childsParam.Value = tvp;

parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
parameters.Add(childsParam);

SqlConnection connection =
    _context.Database.Connection as SqlConnection;
connection.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

cmd.CommandText = storedProcedureName;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

if (parameters != null)
    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());

cmd.Connection = connection;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

connection.Close();
```

Comment: @PeterSmith I check it doing a select and it returns all data, but I need to return that data into a parameter.

Comment: How many items are in your list?  Are you, in effect, trying to return a column to the calling app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a temporary table to recuperate your list from the stored procedure, like the example below :

```
create proc Test
AS BEGIN

SELECT CAST('jkj' AS NVARCHAR(20)) value 

END

DECLARE @tmp TABLE(value nvarchar(20))

INSERT INTO @tmp EXEC GhaziTest

SELECT * from @tmp
```

Comment: Thanks. This answer works but I can't use it with C# SQLCommand.

Comment: Put it in a procedure and call it from your app with SqlCommand

Comment: Sorry, but I have test it and you can return a table from a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

> Stored procedure returns only Integer?

No this is not 100% true. If you are using [RETURN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to return the values from your stored procedure then your statement is true else it is false.

If you want to return string from your stored procedure then you can use SELECT like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT 'test'
END
```

And to return multiple values you can use it like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc 
    @Value1 varchar(20) OUTPUT, 
    @Value2 varchar(20) OUTPUT
AS
    SELECT @Value1 = 'test1', @Value2 = 'test2'
```

and call it like

```
    DECLARE @Value1 varchar(20), @Value2 varchar(20)
    exec myProc @Value1 OUTPUT, @Value2 OUTPUT
    SELECT @Value1, @Value1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need to return more than two values.

Comment: @VansFannel:- I didn't get that. What you are looking for?

Comment: I need to execute this stored procedure in C# code using `SqlCommand`. So, I need to return it as a parameter.

Comment: @VansFannel:- Can you edit your question and add your procedure over there so that it becomes easy to understand what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedures return the type of the field in the `SELECT` statement. You can use `CAST` and `CONVERT` to change the types. For example:
`SELECT CAST(field AS NVARCHAR(20))`

With table value parameters you can set the field type on creation:

```
CREATE TYPE JobSpecifications AS TABLE 
(JobName VARCHAR(50),  AvailableDate Date );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but `JobSpecifications` must be `READONLY` if I use it as a parameter.